# Where are javascript includes relative from?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do an AJAX request using Jquery.

The JS file is located here:

```
root/templates/wooden_tpl/scripts/script.js
```

I try to request data from this file using this function:

```
$.post('ajax/get_blog_info.php',function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

The file is in this directory:

```
root/templates/wooden_tpl/scripts/ajax/get_blog_info.php
```

For some reason this doesn't work.

The file which is including the script.js is contained in the root.

My assumption is that javascript doesn't include relative to it's current pass. True?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is what is the location of the page that is using your "script.js"? If it is using in multiple pages, you must point the ajax page from the root, for eg: $.post("/templates/wooden_tpl/scripts/script.js",function(data) etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important is the context where the javascript is executed. And this is the context of the including file, thus you have to use the including page's path.

Comment: Any way I can use the script.js as the relative path to the ajax document??

Comment: removed my answer as this seems to be the same but you type faster :)

Comment: Wanted to give u a vote up and the answer was already removed :P

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov you need to use the path of the page to call the ajax-document, in your example `templates/wooden_tpl/scripts/ajax/get_blog_info.php`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that now. I was hoping there was a way to include the ajax file relative to the .js document :(

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov - if you desire, you can put some code in to get the base url and manipulate from there - but that is another question :)